# Weight initialization in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Since PyTorch Lightning does most things under the hood, how can I know which weight initialization methods it use for training the model? And how can I modify the initialization method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch Lightning doesn't interfere with weight initialization. It should be same as default PyTorch weights initialization. [This](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a126bbfea3e3b5c09db32c5582eb9bbd341a13e5/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L103) is how Linear layers are initialized.